How to make Button Click only input Number into specific TextBox?
I have 2 TextBoxes: TextBox1 and TextBox2. I also have a button: Button1.
When I press Button1, set the specific TextBox I previously clicked on/selected while operating the app to have the value 1.
Let's say I click TextBox1, and then I press Button1. Then "1" will only appear in TextBox1.
If instead, I click TextBox2, and then I press Button1. Then "1" will only appear in TextBox2 instead.
I tried this code:
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

   Dim intNumberCalc As String
   intNumberCalc = TextBox1.Text

   Select Case intNumberCalc
      Case 1
         If Button1.PerformClick Then
            TextBox1.Text = "1"
         End If
   End Select
End Sub

Which, even I admit is never going to work. I really can't figure out how to make the Button1 press only input on the textbox I clicked on.

You should consider adding a local variable to keep track of the last TextBox that was changed (or its contents).

You need to track the state of what you have clicked on most recently. You have to do this work yourself, by handing events available from the TextBoxes. There is nothing built in to track this for you.

Although it won't immediately solve the problem, it should be Case "1" because intNumberCalc is a string. Probably best not to start its name with "int"! If you set Option Strict On for this project (and set it as the default for new projects) then Visual Studio can point out problems like that for you.

Add an event handler to each TextBox GotFocus event, and record which TextBox is currently focussed into a local variable. When a button is pressed do something like this: FocussedTextbox.Text &= Ctype(Sender,Button).Text
' Local Variable to store the Focussed TextBox
Private FocussedTextbox as TextBox = nothing

' Call this to initialize your handlers Once when the form is first loaded
Protected Sub InitHandlers()
  For Each c As Control In p_PanelContainingTextboxes.Controls
     If TypeOf c Is TextBox Then AddHandler cType(c,TextBox).GotFocus, AddressOf TextBox_GotFocus
  Next
  For Each c As Control In p_PanelContainingButtons.Controls
    If TypeOf c Is Button Then AddHandler cType(c,Button).Clicked, AddressOf NumberButton_Clicked
  Next
End Sub

' Store the Focussed TextBox to the local variable
Protected Sub TextBox_GotFocus(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) 
   FocussedTextBox = Sender
End Sub

' Append the text in the textbox by the text on the button
Protected Sub NumberButton_Clicked(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) 
   FocussedTextbox.Text &= Ctype(Sender,Button).Text
End Sub


May be preferable to use a Handles clause on the event handlers (as in the original code) rather than wiring them up manually.

You could simply store the selected TextBox instance to the Button's Tag, then DirectCast it to Control, when not null -- The Enter event should replace GotFocus

Hope this helps.
Private Sub GotFocusHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.GotFocus, TextBox2.GotFocus
       Me.Button1.Tag = sender
   End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    CType(Me.Button1.Tag, TextBox).Text = "1"
End Sub

